# Estimation and forecasting ARMA: differences between Matlab and Stata

Tags: forecasting, matlab, arima, stata, arma

I have to forecast values from an AR(1) model. My sample is composed of 192 observations. I estimate my model with the 182 first observations and forecast the 10 last observations.

I have done this with Stata using the following code:

```
arima cpi in 1/182, arima(1,0,0)
predict resultat if e(sample)==0
```

The results are the following :

```
results
.1826865
.2050786
.14859
.2937709
.2403078
.1609152
.0748219
.0395317
.1901138
.1172391
```

I try to replicate it in Matlab using the following code:

```
insample = DataY(1:181);
outsample = DataY(182:end);
model = estimate(arima(1,0,0), insample);
results = forecast(model,10, 'Y0', insample);
```

However, I have totally different results, with the forecasts seemingly converging to a specific value:

```
0.1969
0.1885
0.1848
0.1833
0.1826
0.1823
0.1822
0.1822
0.1821
0.1821
```

In addition, the constant of the AR(1) model is not the same in Matlab and Stata (`0.104` for Matlab and `0.1826` for Stata).

Questions:

1. Are these differences normal?
2. Why do the forecasts tend to converge to 0.1821 in Matlab but don't converge to any particular value in Stata?
3. Am I making something wrong in Matlab?

Comment: You seem to use the first 181 observations in MATLAB as opposed to the first 182 in Stata. Furthermore, you can check whether MATLAB and Stata use the same estimation method (e.g., maximum likelihood vs. least squares) and the same initialization of starting values (if any).